# Why its Showing None when it should show Which IP Class it belongs to

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

```
import pandas as pd

ecom = pd.read_csv("data science pack\Ecommerce Purchases.csv")
ecom['Class_IP'] = ecom['IP Address'].apply(lambda x:x.split(".")[0])
def ipc(x):
    if x in range(0,128):
        print("A")
    if x in range(128,192):
        print("B")
    if x in range(192,224):
        print('C')
    if x in range(224,240):
        print("D")
    if x in range(240,255):
        print("E")

ecom['new_c'] = ecom['Class_IP'].apply(lambda y : ipc(y)) 
print(ecom['new_c'])
```

Above is the code. It should print it IP class but it shows None values.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try to pass **int(y)** instead of **y** to ipc() method in lambda function as below:

```
ecom['new_c'] = ecom['Class_IP'].apply(lambda y : ipc(int(y)))
```

It is returning None because ipc function is expecting **int** value and you are passing **string** value to it.

Hope this answer solves your problem.